image that added inside APK file doesn't have ID
im not a developer and e.t.c., just trying to make thematic icons for apps that doesn't have them, i put the image in the apk file through MT manager, but unlike other files it don't have it's own ID. How can i add id to it or how can i put it in the xml file other way?image that i added
image that was already in apk
i tried to optimize APK and place the image directory instead of ID (res/mipmap-xxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher_monochrome.png) but non of these work

Here's a general way to add an image to your project and use it in your XML layout:
Save your image to the res/drawable directory of your Android project.
Give your image a name, for example, my_icon.png.
Use this image in your XML layout like this:
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/my_icon" />


I meant that I need to use this image as a monochrome icon of app, all icons just disappear when i do this –  <monochrome android:layout_width="wrap_content"     android:layout_height="wrap_content"     android:src="@drawable/icon" /> </adaptive-icon>
